# How to display two decimals in MYSQL/PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, double

I'd like to display **£2.00** instead of **£2** or **£3.50** instead of **£3.5**.

These number let's say `price` is defined as `DOUBLE` in a MySQL database. How can I force MySQL or PHP to display the two decimals?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo number_format ($price, 2);
```

Comment: If used in a loop this function will case serious performance issues.

Answer (score 9):

For MySQL, you can use the `format` function:

```
SELECT FORMAT(1.2345, 2);
```

It will return 1.23

For PHP, you can use `number_format` in a similar way:

```
echo number_format(1.2345, 2);
```

Also printing 1.23

Answer (score 5):

[`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) and [`money_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) are your friends!

Answer (score 5):

The other answers are correct insofar as they will *format* a value to two decimal places.

However, given the context in your question, a better answer is **don't use the `DOUBLE` datatype** - at least, not for this purpose.

[Floating-point data types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/floating-point-types.html) like `DOUBLE` are *approximate* and do not represent exact numbers; they are useful for representing continuous quantities like mass or length.  With discrete quantities like currency, they can be disastrous, leading to very unexpected results.  For such quantities you *really* should use instead MySQL's [fixed-point types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fixed-point-types.html) like `DECIMAL`, which enables you to specify the *scale* (i.e. the number of decimal places to store) and therefore will not require any such formatting or rounding to produce correct currency values.